# How do I store the reference to the object in the database, currently it shows as 'null'

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I have a class objects `Comment` and `Bug` as shown below.

```java
public class Comment {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    private String text;
    private LocalDateTime created;
    @DocumentReference
    private Bug bug;
}
```

```
public class Bug {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    // private String projectId;

    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String priority; 
    private String status; 
    private LocalDateTime created;
    private LocalDateTime updated;

    @DocumentReference
    private List<Comment> comments;
}
```

As seen from the classes, these classes have references to each other, a Bug has multiple comments and a Comment has a reference to the bug it belongs to. I am able to create a new comment and add that to the 'comments' field of Bug using the following function in the `CommentService` class as such

```java
public Comment addComment(Comment comment, ObjectId bugId) {

        Optional<Bug> optionalBug = bugRepository.findById(bugId);
        if (optionalBug.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Bug not fowund with ID: " + bugId);
        }

        comment.setCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
        Comment newComment = commentRepository.insert(comment);

        // store the bug reference in the field 'bug'
        Bug bug = optionalBug.get();
        newComment.setBug(bug);

        // associate the comment to the bug
        mongoTemplate.update(Bug.class)
                .matching(Criteria.where("_id").is(bugId))
                .apply(new Update().push("comments", newComment))
                .first();

        // save the comment to the database
        return newComment;

    }
```

But also I want to store the bug reference to which this comment belongs, in the field of `bug` in the `Comment` class. How do I do that? I used the following line in the `CommentService` class`your text` to try and achieve this

```java
// store the bug reference in the field 'bug'
Bug bug = optionalBug.get();
newComment.setBug(bug);
```

But then when I check the comment object, using Postman, after creating the new comment, in the `bug` field I see `null`.

Comment: I'm not a Mongo expert, but you call `setBug` after you've inserted the comment, and you have a comment: `// save the comment to the database` not followed by code to do that.

Comment: Looking at the commenting style -- did ChatGPT write that code? (that's fine, it isn't against the rules to ask about it, I'm just curious)